# Why condition on either the r.v. $X$ or $Y$ and integrate over a product of pdfs rather a single pdf to find this probability density?

Tags: random-variable, density-function, exponential-distribution, conditioning

> Let $X$ have the probability density $f_{X}(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x},
>  \;\; x>0$ and let $Y$ have the probability density $f_{Y}(y)=\lambda
>  e^{-\lambda x},\;\; y>0.$ Find the probability density of $Z=X/Y$.

Answer:

> $$\Pr[Z \le z] = \Pr[X/Y \le z] = \int_{y=0}^\infty \Pr[X \le yz]
>  f_Y(y) \, dy = \int_{y=0}^\infty F_X(yz) f_Y(y) \, dy.$$

Why do we have to integrate over all possible values of $y$ with non-zero support?

Why don't we integrate over the support of the random variable $Z$?

Why do we have

> $$Pr[X\leq yz]f_{Y}(y)dy$$

rather than

$$Pr[X\leq yz]f_{Z}(Z)dz$$

or

$$Pr[X\leq yz]f_{X}(X)\,dx?$$

Also,

Why does one have to use conditioning to solve the problem? Why isn't the solution $$\int_{x=0}^{\infty} Pr[X\leq yz] \, dx?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either condition on $X$ or condition on $Y$. But you can't condition on $f_Z(Z)$ as that is the quantity that you would like to find.

If you would like to condition on $X$ assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent,

\begin{align}
Pr(Z \le z) &= Pr\left(\frac{X}{Y} \le z\right) \\
&=\int_0^\infty Pr(Y \ge \frac{X}{z}|X=x)f_X(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty Pr(Y \ge \frac{x}{z})f_X(x) \, dx \\
\end{align}

Comment: Why does one have to use conditioning to solve the problem? Why isn't the solution $$\int_{x=0}^{\infty} Pr[X\leq yz] dx$$?

Comment: Your $x$ doesn't appear in your integral.  also, $y$ is not defiend in your term. Also, we have not address the randomness of $Y$.

Comment: May I say that $Pr(Z\leq z)=\int_{0}^{\infty} Pr(Y \geq \frac{X}{z} | Y=y) f_Y(y) dy?$

Comment: yes, that is fine. Of course, we have assume that $z$ is positive.